# How to uninstall Visual Studio 2019 from a Windows PC without internet connection

Tags: visual-studio, offline, uninstallation

I need to uninstall Visual Studio 2019 from am offline Windows PC without internet connection.

As soon as I try to uninstall it from "add/remove programs" it opens the Visual Studio Installer application.
Then Visual Studio Installer hangs trying to update itself.

I have tried to launch it from command line with the following options:

```
vs_installer.exe --noWeb --noUpdateInstaller
```

but nevertheless, after a while, it asks to be updated.

I have searched for an offline installer for "Visual Studio Installer", but I haven't found it, it seems that Microsoft does not offers it.

*Update:*

I have tried using InstallCleanup.exe as explained in
[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/uninstall-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)
but it does not exists on the Visual Studio 2019 instance I want to uninstall.
I have tried to copy it (along with its .config file) from another VS Installation I have but It does not work:

```
The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.
```

Thanks

Comment: You can create offline installer via this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2022

Comment: I don't need to create an offline installer. I need to uninstall Visual Studio 2019. But doing this it opens "Visual Studio Installer" that hangs up because the PC is not connected to internet.

Comment: You can try to repair visual studio with offline installer and then delete it.

Comment: The problem is not with a corruption installation, the problem is precisely "Visual studio Installer". It does not work offline, so I can't remove VS2012.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/installation/troubleshoot-installation-issues

Comment: There is no useful solution, almost all is assuming a connected PC and is useful to restore a corrupted installation. My installation is not corrupted, it is perfectly functional. I want only to uninstall it in a clean way and this seems not possible. The only solution appears to manually removing it and manually deleting all the registry keys, and this seems a very unsafe process.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a silly question, but have you searched your VS directory for the InstallCleanup.exe? The documentation says it's located *under* "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio". For me it was "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\InstallCleanup.exe"

This method did work for me when I needed to remove a build tools 2022 layout and replace it with a 2019 one on a firewalled build server. No combination of --noWeb --noUpdateInstaller etc. was working for either a side-by-side install, or uninstalling the 2022 components.

"I say we take off and nuke the entire site from orbit. It's the only way to be sure" -Ripley